# Issue with my routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following error message when I load my app in the browser :

[image: routes]

I am not sure what I have missing here. The route for the home page is correctly defined.

The paths are defined as follows in the view :

```
<li><%= link_to "Home",   root_path %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Help",   help_path %></li>
```

and as follows in the routes file :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root                'static_pages#home'
  get 'help'   =>     'static_pages/help'
end
```

Any idea what I am missing here ?

Thanks !

Comment: on which url, you try to show?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: It shows as expected on the home page, with the header, footer, and body. However, when I click on the help link for instance (in the header), I get the error message as showed on the first post.

Comment: the error message is as showed on the screenshot. it comes when i click on either of the link I created in the header and footer (help, about, contact)

Comment: This is weirs, as that does not seem to be an exception. Have you restarted the server after changing routes?

Comment: I don't thank the wuss who downvoted my question. It actually was a typo in the tutorial I am following (which is btw maybe the best RoR tutorial available at the moment, and whose author I am about to notify). I know, you must be a programming genius.

Comment: To the downvoter: an explanation about it is always appreciated, interesting for the guy asking and for others to learn about the rules here.

Comment: Hey @harvey, you could link the tutorial for completeness and to help others in the same situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route is wrong. You need to rename your routes to change the slash for a "#", assuming `help` is a separate action in your `static_pages_controller.rb`, as well as for any other routes in your header (`about`, `help`, etc).

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'help'   =>     'static_pages#help'
end
```

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks ! Well, the tutorial I am following got it wrong.

Comment: Nope. I'm the one who answered ;)

Comment: ok. I'd like to upvote, but unfortunately thanks to the f*g who downvoted my question, i'm now down to below 15 points, and the system does not allow me to up/down vote. Sorry mate, I don't know what I can do at the moment. Will upvote later when my reputation points are up above 15.

Comment: hahaha no problem mate. There goes an upvote to your question anyway :)  It's not the best of the questions actually, but I see no need to delete it.